# three.js MeshLambertMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

Dear all: My models with MeshLambertMaterial consume about 1.6GB memory, which is excess the capability of 32-bit Chrome browser. When using Basic Material instead, the memory consumption is almost at the same level around 456mb. Nevertheless, no 3D-like-feeling towards objects in scenes.  Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have complex geometry/huge texture files.
What I suggest is to decrease geometry complexity, try smaller textures and re-use once instantiated objects which are not visible on the screen

A good read about performance tweaking
: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/hobbit/